# XACML Authzforce PDP Custom Policies

Tags: authzforce

Authzforce PDP does it support custom policies apart from xacml policies?. We are able to send xacml request tp PDP but as the policy creation is in xacml is complex we decided to create our own policies using json format, does Authforce able to support policies written in nonxacaml format? Need some assistance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write policies in ALFA, then use the [ALFA Compiler](https://www.axiomatics.com/alfa/) (1.2 or later), i.e. `alfac.jar` to convert to XACML before sending the policies to AuthzForce. More info in the ALFA 1.2 User Guide (provided with the Compiler), in section *XACML generation using the standalone ALFA compiler*.

As an alternative, the AuthzForce project [xacml-json-model](https://github.com/authzforce/xacml-json-model) provides:

- A JSON schema for policies, closely equivalent to XACML, [more info in the README](https://github.com/authzforce/xacml-json-model#xacmljson-policy-json-schema-and-validation);
- A few [examples of policies in this JSON format](https://github.com/authzforce/xacml-json-model/tree/develop/src/test/resources/xacml%2Bjson.samples/Policies/valid) for testing, with various levels of complexity;
- XSLT stylesheets to translate this JSON policies into XACML 3.0 automatically, with help of your favorite XSLT 3.0 library/processor, [more info in the README](https://github.com/authzforce/xacml-json-model#converting-xacmlxml-policyset-to-json-and-vice-versa), e.g. in a command line with SAXON XSLT library:

```
$ java -jar Saxon-HE-9.8.0-15.jar -xsl:xacml-policy-json-to-xml.xsl -it inJsonFile=MyPolicy.json
```